# md-autocomplete ng-pattern="..." does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have the issue with [`<md-autocomplete>`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) component which is shown in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dma_k/j9afow1L/3/):

`<md-autocomplete ng-pattern="...">` does not work. I would expect that if some text is entered into `Tax` field (like `zzz`) the field is be marked as red as only numbers [1..99] are accepted by regex `ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d?$/"`. Actually `required` works fine: when the field is empty, it is triggered as invalid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That seems to have been a bug with Angular Material. It was apparently fixed in 1.1.4:

[ng-pattern for md-autocomplete #9755](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9755)

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dma_k/j9afow1L/3/). All I did was update the two angular-material libraries.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with ng-pattern got fixed in version 1.1.14. I have updated the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j9afow1L/11/) and added latest angularjs-material.js

I have not changed ng-pattern, it remains same.

```
ng-pattern="/^[1-9]/"
```

Now the field will change to red if other than number is entered.

Answer (score 2):

**Just change your pattern by**: `ng-pattern="^[1-9]\d?$"`

Comment: I have tried to change it to the pattern you've said (see [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j9afow1L/5/)), however it has no effect. More over `<input ng-model="model.income" ng-pattern="^[1-9]\d+$" />` does not work as expected as well (previously was marked as red). Could you please update the demo so that it works? Thanks!